# AWS Lambda(Linux kernel version – 4.4.51-40.60.amzn1.x86_64) throwing MissingMethodException at Interop.Crypto.Pkcs12Parse

Tags: amazon-web-services, .net-core, aws-lambda

When I run below console application from window it works

```
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;    
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine("File exists: " + File.Exists("key.p12"));
    var certificate = new X509Certificate2("key.p12", "notasecret");
    Console.WriteLine("Success");
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

but when I tried in AWS lambda its throwing error

```
.ctor: MissingMethodException
at Interop.Crypto.Pkcs12Parse(SafePkcs12Handle p12, String pass, SafeEvpPKeyHandle& pkey, SafeX509Handle& cert, SafeX509StackHandle& ca)
at Internal.Cryptography.Pal.OpenSslPkcs12Reader.Decrypt(String password)
at Internal.Cryptography.Pal.PkcsFormatReader.TryReadPkcs12(OpenSslPkcs12Reader pfx, String password, Boolean single, ICertificatePal& readPal, List`1& readCerts)
at Internal.Cryptography.Pal.PkcsFormatReader.TryReadPkcs12(SafeBioHandle bio, String password, Boolean single, ICertificatePal& readPal, List`1& readCerts)
at Internal.Cryptography.Pal.CertificatePal.FromBio(SafeBioHandle bio, String password)
at Internal.Cryptography.Pal.CertificatePal.FromFile(String fileName, String password, X509KeyStorageFlags keyStorageFlags)
at System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate..ctor(String fileName, String password, X509KeyStorageFlags keyStorageFlags)
at System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2..ctor(String fileName, String password)
at test_openssl_lambda.Functions.TriggerSync() in /tmp/src818283224/src/test-openssl-lambda/test_openssl_lambda/Function.cs:line 21
at lambda_method(Closure , Stream , Stream , ContextInfo )
```

Below is my project.json

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0-*",
  "buildOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": false
  },

  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
      "type": "platform",
      "version": "1.0.0"
    },

    "Amazon.Lambda.Core": "1.0.0",
    "Amazon.Lambda.APIGatewayEvents": "1.1.0",
    "Amazon.Lambda.Serialization.Json": "1.1.0",
    "Amazon.Lambda.Tools": {
      "type": "build",
      "version": "1.5.0"
    },

    "System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates": "4.3.0"
  },

  "tools": {
    "Amazon.Lambda.Tools": "1.5.0"
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.0": {
      "imports": "dnxcore50"
    }
  }
}
```

And calling Function.cs (which is same as above console application)

```
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
using Amazon.Lambda.Core;

[LambdaSerializer(typeof(Amazon.Lambda.Serialization.Json.JsonSerializer))]
public void Trigger()
{
    Console.WriteLine("File exists: " + File.Exists("Key.p12"));
    var certificate = new X509Certificate2("Key.p12", "notasecret");
    Console.WriteLine("Success");
}
```

It throws exception because its not able to do DllImport System.Security.Cryptography.Native.OpenSsl in AWS Lambda environment(Linux kernel version – 4.4.51-40.60.amzn1.x86_64)
Can someone help me in fixing the issue? i.e., helping me to get installing System.Security.Cryptography.Native.OpenSsl in AWS Lambda?

Answer (score 2):

This exception happens when the underlying machine doesn't have the required OpenSSL version prerequisite installed, which seems to be the case on AWS Lambda.
See https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/14356

Answer (score 0):

Now I have changed my project to .Net Core 2.1 and its working.